# Does redirecting a pointer introduce memory leak?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have two pointers:

```
int *a = new int;
int *b = new int;
```

Now I set `b` equal to `a`:

```
b=a;
```

My concern is about the memory that `b` was initially pointing at. When I redirect `b` to point to the memory that `a` points to and both point to the same memory location. **What about the previous memory location of b, is it freed or it is in memory leak?**

To prevent memory leak should I do it this way:

```
delete b;
b=a;
```

Comment: Of course that code leaks memory like a sieve.

Comment: There is no garbage collection in C++, so without the `delete` it is a memory leak. (Also in modern C++ you should prefer smart pointers over raw pointers for that reason)

Comment: If you think you need pointers, first of you rarely if ever need it for single values of simple types like `int`. Then consider the standard containers [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then consider smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Then and only then consider raw plain pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a memory leak. You didn't `delete` what you `new`-ed as `b` no longer points at the original location. Try this:

```
int* a = new int;
int* b = new int;
int* originalb = b;
b = a;
delete originalb;
delete b; // or a
```

given that `a` and `b` remain the same.
That being said prefer [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) to raw pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It's a leak.

You should use smart pointers instead.